# How to send class definition from host to client using Protocol Buffers?

Tags: c#, tcp, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I'm currently trying to use protobuf-net to create an object of a class over a TCP connection. I'm relatively new to this so I'm following the tutorial at https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/GettingStarted

On my host I have this code defining a class "Person"

```
    [ProtoContract]
    class Person {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Name {get; set:}
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public Address Address {get; set;}
    }
```

and this block that serializes the class as a .bin file :

```
var person = new Person {
    Id = 12345, Name = "Fred",
    Address = new Address {
        Line1 = "Flat 1",
        Line2 = "The Meadows"
    }
};
using (var file = File.Create("person.bin")) {
    Serializer.Serialize(file, person);
}
```

I copied and pasted the person.bin file into the project folder on my client and used the following block to read the .bin file and output a segment of the file.

```
Person newPerson;
using (var file = File.OpenRead("person.bin")) {
    newPerson = Serializer.Deserialize<Person>(file);
}
Console.WriteLine("The name is: " + newPerson.name);
```

Unfortunately, this only works when I also have the code defining the class "Person" on the client. **How can I send a definition of the class from the host to the client over a TCP connection using Protocol Buffers so I can create an object on the client?**

Comment: I'm not sure you can, and not sure why you want to. What advantage is there in doing it like this over including a portable class library containing the class definition on the client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, all parts of a system communicating using protobufs need to know the definitions of those protobufs in order to work with them (your receiving class must know a priori the structure of a `Person`, and how to deserialize it).

It's inconvenient and inefficient, as it's not the usual case, but you can use a self-describing message to simultaneously send structure and data: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#self-description

Answer (score 4):

The link above is a great resource. I'd like to add a bit of a background. When you tell protoc to generate the descriptor file by the --descriptor_set_out option it generates a file that describes your class.

Many language bindings like node.js' is using this descriptor file to understand the protobuf encoded messages rather than using a generated language stub. Node.js for example is using this technique to dynamically interpret protobuf messages.

The point is that in a compiled language like C# or C++ you don't always need the generated stub code. However the stub code is likely be more efficient than interpreting the protobuf message using these descriptors.